# Eleventy, frontmatter data not being evaluated

Tags: yaml-front-matter, eleventy

I have a template that looks like this:

```
---
date: "2016-01-01T06:00-06:00"
value: "/{{ page.date | date: '%Y/%m/%d' }}/index.html"
---

Value prints: {{ value }} <br/>
But we expect: {{ page.date | date: '%Y/%m/%d' }}/index.html <br/>
```

When I render the site then the site looks like this:

```
Value prints: /{{ page.date | date: '%Y/%m/%d' }}/index.html
But we expect: 2016/01/01/index.html
```

I really want the `value` parameter to have the expected value.

As far as I can tell, this sort of thing should work. I want to use this technique to calculate permalinks. My thinking is based on https://www.11ty.dev/docs/permalinks/

I'm running eleventy 0.12.1

Things I've tried:

- yaml, json and js frontmatter
- markdown template
- njk template
- literally copy pasting sample code from the docs

At this point I think Eleventy might have a bug

Answer (score 4):

At the moment of writing, eleventy doesn't support template syntax in any frontmatter fields except the permalink field:

> `permalink`: Change the output target of the current template. Normally, you cannot use template syntax to reference other variables in your data, but permalink is an exception.

[Source](https://www.11ty.dev/docs/data-configuration/#configure-your-templates)

Instead, you can use [computed data](https://www.11ty.dev/docs/data-computed/), which allows you to set frontmatter data based on other frontmatter fields. Something like this should work:

```yaml
date: "2016-01-01T06:00-06:00"
eleventyComputed:
    value: "/{{ page.date | date: '%Y/%m/%d' }}/index.html"
```